# Split 1 Row Into Multiple Ones

Tags: sql, excel, shell

I have the following comma separated file:

```
FName, LName, Family Role
Stan, Smith, Husband | Father | Son
Francine, Smith, Wife | Mother
Steve, Smith, Son
Hayley, Smith, Wife | Daughter
Roger, Smith, Alien
```

I desire the following output:

```
Fname, LName, Family Role
Stan, Smith, Husband
Stan, Smith, Father
Stan, Smith, Son
Francine, Smith, Wife
Francine, Smith, Mother
Steve, Smith, Son
Hayley, Smith, Wife
Hayley, Smith, Daughter
Roger, Smith, Alien
```

I have plenty of leeway as to which tool/language I can use to achieve this. If done in Excel(VBA), SQL, Shell, Powershell, whatever really.

Comment: I tried splitting that column into multiple ones using the Split() function in VBA but I was not very successful as some have 2 roles, others have more than 2 which is where my code failed.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
$ awk -F' *[,|]' '{for (i=3;i<=NF;i++) print $1,$2,$i}' OFS=, file
FName, LName, Family Role
Stan, Smith, Husband
Stan, Smith, Father
Stan, Smith, Son
Francine, Smith, Wife
Francine, Smith, Mother
Steve, Smith, Son
Hayley, Smith, Wife
Hayley, Smith, Daughter
Roger, Smith, Alien
```

#### How it works

awk implicitly loops over every line in a file and divides each line into fields.

- `-F' *[,|]'`

  This tells awk to use as a field separator spaces (optional) followed by one of `,` or `|`.  In this way, the first name is field 1, the second is field 2, and the remaining fields, one for each role, are numbered starting with 3.
- `for (i=3;i<=NF;i++) print $1,$2,$i`

  This tells awk to print one line for each of the roles.
- `OFS=,`

  This tells awk to use a comma for the output field separator.

#### Improvement

The above works unless it is possible for a first name or last name to contain a `|`.  If that were to happen, then the fields would be split wrong.  We can avoid that with a slightly more complex command. This command divides the lines into fields based on `,`.  Then, the third field is divided into roles by splitting it on `|`:

```
$ awk -F' *,' '{n=split($3, role, "|"); for (i=1;i<=n;i++) print $1,$2,role[i]}' OFS=, file
FName, LName, Family Role
Stan, Smith, Husband 
Stan, Smith, Father 
Stan, Smith, Son
Francine, Smith, Wife 
Francine, Smith, Mother
Steve, Smith, Son
Hayley, Smith, Wife 
Hayley, Smith, Daughter
Roger, Smith, Alien
```

Answer (score 0):

Perl version of @John1024's solution:

`perl -F'\s*[,|]' -lane 'for ($i=2;$i<=$#F;$i++){print "$F[0],$F[1],$F[$i]"}' file`

Fields in perl start with `$F[0]`, whereas awk starts with `$1`